# Export/Download a ReportViewer Report using "Save As..." dialog or open in a new Tab or Window

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, reporting, reportviewer

I am successfully able to export a report from a report viewer to a PDF file using this code:

```
private void ExportReport(string exportType)
{
    if (ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.ReportPath == null)
    {
        LiteralReportErrorMessage.Text = "Please select a report to view before exporting.";
        return;
    }

    Warning[] warnings;
    string[] streamIds;
    string mimeType = string.Empty;
    string encoding = string.Empty;
    string extension = string.Empty;
    string filename = "RSLF";

    byte[] bytes = ReportViewerControl.LocalReport.Render(exportType, null, out mimeType, out encoding, out extension, out streamIds, out warnings);

    Response.Buffer = true;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = mimeType;
    Response.AddHeader("content-dispostion", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "." + extension);
    Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    Response.Flush();
}
```

The problem I am having is that this method is called from a button click event handler. The handler does nothing else but call this method then return.
The report exports just fine, but instead of the user being prompted with a "Save As..." dialog (as I really would prefer) the PDF opens in the browser in the same tab that the original page was on. When the user clicks the "Back" button, all of the report settings are lost and need to be re-entered.

I don't care if the report opens in the browser, but is it possible to force it to open in a new tab or window? Even better, is it possible for me to alter the method above to prompt the user to save the file rather than show it in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I actually found my problem...I misspelled "content-disposition". Changing it from "content-dispostion" to "content-disposition" worked.
How silly!

Answer (score 0):

Just try to erase any buffered HTML output with the **Clear** method in your **Response**. This code should prompt a "Save As" dialog.

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = mimeType;
Response.AppendHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "." + extension);
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.SuppressContent = true;
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```